# Walkspeed: [hum walkspeed]

Tags: lua, label, roblox

How can I make my label say "Walkspeed [walkspeed]"

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Slider = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Prem.ScrollingFrame.Slider

script.Parent.Changed:Connect(function()
    local scale = script.Parent.Position.X.Scale
    local number = math.floor(scale*100)
    local volume = number
    local humainoid = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if humainoid then
        humainoid.WalkSpeed = 16 + (1*volume)
        Slider.labelText.Text = "Walkspeed: " ..tostring(humainoid.Walkspeed)
    end
end)
```

I tried making new vaiables but it didn't work

Comment: What is `script.Parent`? Does the `Changed` event ever fire? Could you be more specific about what exactly doesn't work about your code?